# Solving complex polynomial equations

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm trying to solve this:

$3z^4 -z^3 +2z^2 -z +3 = 0$ "given no root is real"

The question gives us: $\frac {1} {z^n} +z^n = 2Cos(n \theta)$ and says hence or otherwise solve the above. I'm a bit stumped as i'm only getting real solutions.

I'm dividing through by $z^2$ to get: $3(z^2 +\frac {1}{z^2}) -(z+\frac {1}{z}) +2 = 0$, and then when I use the above identity I get:

$6Cos(2\theta) -2Cos(\theta) +2 = 0$. After using trig identity and solving: $6Cos^2(\theta) -Cos(\theta) -2 = 0$, I get real roots: 
$Cos(\theta) = \frac {2}{3}$,  and $Cos(\theta) =-\frac {1}{2} $.

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. If someone could point me in the right direction, i'd be most grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from a typo in your equation where the middle term should be $-2\cos(\theta)$ instead of $-\cos(\theta)$, I also got the same results as you for the values of $\cos(\theta)$.

As for what to do next, substitute these values in what the original question gives to determine $z$. For example, with $\cos(\theta) = \frac{2}{3}$, you get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{z} + z & = 2\left(\frac{2}{3}\right) \\
3 + 3z^2 & = 4z \\
3z^2 - 4z + 3 & = 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Now, you can use the quadratic formula to get

$$z = \frac{4 \pm \sqrt{4^2 - 4(9)}}{6} = \frac{4 \pm 2\sqrt{-5}}{6} = \frac{2 \pm \sqrt{5}i}{3} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

I'll leave it to you to handle the case where $\cos(\theta) = -\frac{1}{2}$ to get the other $2$ values of $z$.

Note that although the RHS of the formula you're given, i.e., $2\cos(n\theta)$, is real, it doesn't mean the $z$ on the LHS has to be real, as \eqref{eq2A} shows.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Answers are the back of the book are: (2+- i.sqrt(5))/3 and (-1+- i.sqrt(3))/2. Is the book wrong or have we both made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: @Noobcoder You're welcome. Thanks for providing the book answers. When I checked again now, I saw I had made a mistake in the RHS of my ($1$) where I forgot to multiply by $2$ since it's $2\cos(\theta)$. I'm sorry about that. However, I've corrected it now, with the revised calculations giving the first book answer. I trust you will get the other answer when you solve using $\cos(\theta)  = -\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Hi John, stupid question but since we have $Cos(\theta)$, could we just as well say: $z = Cos(\theta) + iSin(\theta)$, and sub the values into this instead to get the same answer? And we can use the $Cos^2 (\theta) +Sin^2 (\theta) =1$ to convert the $Sin$. Are both acceptable or is there something wrong with this approach? Thanks again! Appreciate the quick responses.

Comment: @Noobcoder It's past $4$ a.m. my time and I should have been asleep a few hours ago. Note I just noticed I forgot to update my first term in ($2$), so I had it as $2$ instead of $4$, so when divided by $2$, I had $1$ instead of $2$. However, I've fixed that now so it does *actually* match what you stated the book's answer is.

Comment: I subbed in $cos(\theta)$ and $sin(\theta)$ and I'm getting the same complex roots as the book. Also, the mod of z is 1. I think the sleep deprivation is getting to you! :) z = 2/3 +- sqrt5/3). (minor typo - you wrote 1/3 in the comments). Mod of this is indeed 1, so |z| = r = 1.

Comment: @Noobcoder Actually, I had left and was getting read to go to bed when I realized with the corrected value the modulus is $1$ (my mistake was using my earlier incorrect value). Using [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula), with $z = cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)$, you get that $z^n + z^{-n} = \cos(n\theta) + i\sin(n\theta) + \cos(-n\theta) + i\sin(-n\theta) = 2\cos(n\theta)$. Thus, the $\theta$ in this case is the same, as you suggested. I'm sorry, once again, for my earlier mistake. However, as you can see, my idea of a quadratic equation does also work.

Comment: Yup both work. Thanks for all your help again and goodnight!

Answer (score 1):

You are right the polynomial has no real roots

$3*z^4-z^3+2*z^2-z+3 = 0$

It's roots are
$z_1 = -(\sqrt(3)*i+1)/2, z_2 = (\sqrt(3)*i-1)/2,z_3 = -(\sqrt(5)*i-2)/3,z_4 = (\sqrt(5)*i+2)/3$

But you made a mistake in your calculations, dividing the equation by $z^2$ to get
$3*(z^2+1/(z^2))-(z+1/(z))+2 = 0$
$3×2*\cos(2×\theta)-2×\cos(\theta)+2 = 0$

$3×2×( 2×\cos(\theta)^2-1)-2×\cos(\theta)+2 = 0$
$3×2×2×\cos(\theta)^2-3×2-2×\cos(\theta)+2 = 0$
$12×\cos(\theta)^2-2×\cos(\theta)-4 = 0$

Now we have to solve this quadratic, which has roots
$\cos(\theta) = -1/2$ and $\cos(\theta) = 2/3$
Then $\theta = \arccos(-1/2)$ and $\theta = \arccos(2/3)$

Now the angle is this ( working in radian )

$\theta = 2*\pi/3$ and $\theta = \arccos(2/3)$

I suggest you understand the true meaning of that identity and de' moivres theorem, because the $\theta$ contains the natural logarithm.

$\theta = -i×\log(z)$

Where $z$ is the root of your polynomial, therefore
$z = exp(\theta × i )$

Which then becomes
$z = exp((2*\pi/3)*i)$ and $z = exp(\arccos(2/3)*i)$

Which are the roots of your polynomial, offcourse it's conjugate is also a root